# Average of N number of matrix

Tags: matrices, statistics, average

I am looking for a new operation to find average of matricies which I will use instead of others

Let me give an example:

There are `A`, `B`, `C` matricies. I am going to find an average matrix of them.

The first I have used `mean`:

```
average=(A+B+C)/3
```

The second is `median`:

```
average=median(A,B,C) % I have used Matlab function to find it
```

What kind of another calculation I can use to compute the average matrix of  A,B,C?

**Edit 1:** The main task is to find a way how to simplify computation. I have more than 3 matrices, about 1000. I can group some of them, according to a theory I used they are similar. If they are similar, I can average them, find one that I will use instead of them. 
Actually I don't know what kind of average instead of mean and median I can use to do it. Can I use  "mode"  for matrices?

Comment: The correct choice of average depends _entirely_ on what you want to do with that average. Your average of three matrices should be decided by "If I wanted use a single matrix three times, rather than $A, B$ and $C$, which such matrix would give the same end result?" As you can see, the result is obviously going to depend on what meaning you put into the word "use".

Comment: @Arthur I am looking for a single average matrix which I will use instead `A, B,C` in mu computation. My goal: find the average matrix that gives me less error.

Comment: And, as I said, that is going to depend entirely on what exactly this computation is.

Comment: @user36610 The point is, how to you define the error? If it is the classical mean square error, then the classical *mean* will do it. If not, we need more information

Comment: @Damien I have editted

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Arthur, the method you should use depends on your use case.
 Just to give you ideas of possible averages try these: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average
Of course those are not for matrices, but you can use them on all entries separately.